# Ayuda con consulta SQL UNION y PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estoy intentando unificar 3 tablas y mostrar el resultado en PHP, estoy usando el siguiente código pero me devuelve una pagina en blanco.

Tengo 3 tablas de 2 columnas (Golosina y Precio)

La consulta SQL me devuelve el resultado de todas las golosinas con un valor a $25 en una tabla como lo quiero, para eso hago lo siguiente:

```
SELECT 'arcor' AS Golosina, tabla1 AS Precio FROM arcor WHERE PRECIO = '25'
UNION
SELECT 'terrabusi' AS Golosina, tabla2 AS Precio FROM terrabusi WHERE PRECIO = '25'
UNION
SELECT 'kelops' AS Golosina, tabla3 AS Precio FROM kelops WHERE PRECIO = '25
```

El codigo que fui armando fue el siguiente:

```
<?php
$set = ("25");
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "pass", "dbname");
if ($set){
$show="SELECT 'arcor' AS Golosina, tabla1 AS Precio FROM arcor WHERE PRECIO = '%$set%'
UNION
SELECT 'terrabusi' AS Golosina, tabla2 AS Precio FROM terrabusi WHERE PRECIO = '%$set%'
UNION
SELECT 'kelops' AS Golosina, tabla3 AS Precio FROM kelops WHERE PRECIO = '%$set%'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $show);
?>
<?php
while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><b>Golosina:</b> </th>";
    echo $rows['Golosina'];
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><b>Precio:</b> </th>";
    echo $rows['Precio'];
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
}
}
else {
    echo "No se encontraron resultados.";

}

?>
```

Comment: ¿A qué se refiere `A.COLOR = 'AZUL'`? ¿Hay acaso **una tercera tabla**? Ahí `A` sería el *alias*  de una tabla que no es ni `MARCA1` ni `MARCA2`¿?

Comment: Y en ambas tablas estás guardando el nombre del color? 
- Si, en una va con el nombre de una marca y en la otra con otra marca

¿A qué se refiere A.COLOR = 'AZUL'? ¿Hay acaso una tercera tabla? Ahí A sería el alias de una tabla que no es ni MARCA1 ni MARCA2¿?
- Puede haber un error ahi, quizas sea AND N.COLOR = 'AZUL' para que me traiga de ambas tablas todo lo AZUL junto con sus marcas.

Comment: Si en una tabla tienes 4 filas con color azul y en la otra hay 5 fila con el mismo color, el resultado serán 20 filas totales. Entiendo que debería existir una relación natural entre las dos tablas que no sea solo algo tan genérico como el color. ¿Que son estas dos tablas? es decir ¿que representan? ¿podrías también agregar la estructura de las mismas?

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow, ¿Has hecho el [tour]?, si no, te invito a hacerlo. Además, sugiero que completes tu pregunta mostrando unos cuantos registros de cada tabla y el resultado que esperas obtener (con exactamente esos registros). Un saludo y, de nuevo, bienvenido/a.

Comment: Si en `MARCA1` hay dos registros AZUL y dos registros ROJO, y lo mismo en `MARCA2`, ¿qué salida exacta esperas obtener? ¿Hay relación entre los registros, o en realidad quieres los registros de ambas tablas en una única lista (con un `UNION`)?

Comment: Gracias por todas sus respuestas. En base a la ultima pregunta de Andrew lo que necesito es obtener los registros de todas las tablas que como única coincidencia sea AZUL

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa el boton [edit] y agrega a la pregunta un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada y que queres como salida...

Comment: ¿No estarás buscando hacer un `union`? es decir `select * from marca1 where color = 'azul' union all select * from marca2 where color = 'azul'`

Comment: Ok ahi modifique correctamente mi consulta para que se entienda y me puedan ayudar. gracias

Comment: mas alla que leo tu pregunta, y no se cual es tu duda, una tabla por "marca" es un grave error. cual es el problema con este codigo?

Comment: Mi duda es que es lo que esta mal en el codigo ya que me devuelve una pagina en blanco sin errores. Una tabla por marca no es un error por que los registros se llevan de manera individual entonces lo que yo necesito hacer es unificar las 3 tablas y que me devuelva todas las golosinas que valen $25 en una columna que se llame Golosina y otra que se llame precio. Espero haber sido claro, muchas gracias

Comment: una tabla por marca viola la 3 forma normal de la base de datos..si tuvieras 100 marcas, serian 100 tablas, y no esta bien. Pero bueno... supongamos que esta bien.. el error es que devuelve una pagina en blanco? no hay errores en la consola? esa query funciona en la base de datos?

Comment: y otra duda mas grande.. si tu variable es set, y el precio es un varchar (es un varchar? no es un numero?) porque mandas el query como '%$set%'??? no deberia ser simplemente '$set'???

Comment: Entiendo que puede violar las formas tradicionales, pero es por eso que acudo a stackoverflow con el fin de poder resolverlo ya que es el problema que tengo. Esa query funciona en la base de datos correctamente. El error en la pagina es blanco y en la consola tambien. mando el query %set% por que si me funciona queria utilizarlo para combinar con otros valores pero no importa.. supongamos que lo deje en $set